# Struts2 POST Causing Connection Reset when Proxied by Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, struts2, mod-proxy

When POSTing (or GETting) certain simple text values to our Struts2 (2.3.15.2) application when proxied by Apache HTTP server, we are getting a "The connection was reset" message within the browser (reported by Firebug as an Aborted request).  It appears the server is never contacted at all (there are no entries in apache's access/error logs for the failed request).

The strange thing is that only certain string values trigger this error.  We've found that the following key words: `control, find, services` when combined with any of the following symbols: `"';<>|'` cause the error. For example, the value `control;` results in an error but not `test;`.

Or a more complex example:

```
string containing the word find and a special character like >
```

Causes error but not:

```
string containing the word notfind and a special character like >
```

**When we access the application via tomcat directly, we do not run into this problem.**

We've deployed a simple struts2 java web application containing the most basic of views/controllers in an attempt to isolate the problem we are running into.  Here's the view:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="test.action" method="post">
      Value: <textarea type="text" name="value"></textarea> <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <hr/>
    Value is: ${value}
  </body>
</html>
```

And the action:

```
public class TestAction {
  private String value;

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String execute() {
    return "success";
  }
}
```

We are running Apache/2.2.10 (Linux/SUSE) with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp.  Tomcat version is 6.0.18.  Here's the configuration:

```
ProxyPass /ConnectionResetTestApp ajp://localhost:8009/ConnectionResetTestApp
```

Using mod_proxy_http with the following configuration produces the same broken behavior:

```
ProxyPass /ConnectionResetTestApp http://localhost:8080/ConnectionResetTestApp
ProxyPassReverse /ConnectionResetTestApp http://localhost:8080/ConnectionResetTestApp
```

This example application can be tested out at: http://post.idaho.gov/ConnectionResetTestApp/

Any ideas on why this is happening and how we can prevent this type of error?

Comment: Post your apache configuration.

Comment: How did you find those *specific* words? :)

Comment: Do you happen to use mod_security? Does it work better with mod_proxy_http? Do you have anything before Apache in your environment? Did you test with newer version of all those products?

Comment: @AleksandrM  VERY PAINFULLY...  It was a trial and error situation.  In an application we received complaints about the connection reset.  Then we started receiving more complaints SO...  We asked the user for the input they were using.  Then just started bisecting the input until we narrowed it down.  After we found the first case I started grabbing random text from the internet until we narrowed it down more.  I am sure there are more keywords but... I guess we will leave it at that for now.

Comment: @CédricC We are not using mod_security.  And, yes, the same behavior is present when using mod_proxy_http instead (I'll update question). Apache should be the first thing we're hitting (not going through a proxy for Internet access).  No, we have not tested yet with newer versions.

Comment: This might be a red herring, but your connection type to the first request (just to get the form) is 'keep alive'.  Is there a reason for that?  Can you try a 'close' connection type instead?

Comment: @Brice it's strange, without anything before Apache or using mod_security, there should be a server header, and i can't see it on your test webapp.

Comment: @Brice another thing, your struts as well as tomcat version is vulnerable to several security flaws. You should at least correct it for that public test.

Comment: @Brice again, for information the same thing can be observed with apache only I think. Testing that url http://post.idaho.gov/gsgd?gdf=find%3E got me the same connection reset. I think you can take tomcat out of the equation.

Comment: @Brice From more tests, it also seems to happen before the request get to apache. Any firewall ? any log on your system about packet rejected?

Comment: @CédricC Good work eliminating Tomcat!  No there are no errors that I can see on the server at all (where would I look beyond the apache access and error log files?)  I'll follow up with our firewall administrator -- I think you are definitely pointing us in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to point this out again...  The connection used to the server in the get request is a 'keep-alive' not a 'closed'.  Could you try a 'closed' connection instead of 'keep-alive'?  You can see the 'keep-alive' connection with firebug.

Comment: Mystery solved!  Unbeknownst to us, an intrusion prevention system was running on the firewall preventing potentially malicious command injection. The workaround: use SSL so that the IPS could not analyze the submission and block it.  @CédricC, thanks for your help on this one, your comments got us looking in the right place.  If you'd like to leave an answer you will be rewarded!

Comment: @Brice glad you got it working,I'll try to write an useful answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was posted in the comments, so I will just write what process I followed to help you.

From the description of the problem (connection lost when a request contains some specific strings), there could be several causes :

1. Struts
2. Tomcat
3. Apache
4. the OS

The fact that you tested directly on tomcat implies (almost) that Struts and Tomcat are not the cause. It could be the Tomcat AJP connector, hence my question about mod_proxy_http.
Then, thanks to your test app, I saw that a simple request which does not even get to the tomcat get rejected the same way (http://post.idaho.gov/gsgd?gdf=find%3E)  so tomcat out.

The fact that there is no line in error_log or access_log implies the request doesn't even get to apache, so there is something before in the network. As Apache is directly public, there must be some firewall rule blocking all tcp packet on port 80 containing those strings.